# How to compare data from a worksheet and operate in a different one?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that classifies data into different groups (to simplify lets say each case -except for one- is compounded by two rows), when a change is made to the first row of the group I want the macro to identify with which case I was originally dealing and adapt the data to the format of the "new" case, however information regarding changes that were applied can be found in one worksheet (LogDetails) and the information I need to determine which was the original case is in another worksheet (20190328)

The problem it's in the comparison sentence at the IF-condition, because I want to know the content of two different cells in two different worksheets in order to determine actions

- I already have some code to track changes and save them in the worksheet
- The code I wrote to adapt data to the new case format should work if I get to solve this problem (couldn't actually test it yet)

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub apply_case_change()
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim k1 As Integer
    Dim c1 As Integer
    Dim row_counter As Integer

    lRow = Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)

    For k1 = 2 To lRow
    row_counter = Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 8).Value 'Counter for visible sheet
        If Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 9).Value = 28 Then
            '----Case 1
            If Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 2).Value = "FB" And Worksheets("20190328").Cells(row_counter, 37).Value = "Kaufteil mit Beistellung" Then
                Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 10).Value = 1
                Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 11).Value = 2
            ElseIf Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 2).Value = "FB" And IsEmpty(Worksheets("20190328").Cells(row_counter, 37).Value) = False Then
                Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 10).Value = 1
                Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 11).Value = 3
                
            ElseIf Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 2).Value = "FB" And IsEmpty(Worksheets("20190328").Cells(row_counter + 1, 28).Value) = True Then
                Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 10).Value = 1
                Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 11).Value = 4
            End If
        End If
    Next k1


'_____________________________________ CASE 4


    For k1 = 3 To lRow
        c1 = Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 8).Value 'ROW Counter for visible sheet
        If Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 10).Value = 1 And Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 11).Value = 4 Then
            'CHANGE FROM 1 to 4
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 39).Value = Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1, 28).Value 'Copy xxx number
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 28).Value = "HZ" 'Update Type Column
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 53).Value = 4 'Update tag
            c1 = c1 + 1 'So we skip the whole set (EACH CASE 1 CONTAINS 2 LINES, one after the other)
            
        ElseIf Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 10).Value = 2 And Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 11).Value = 4 Then
            'CHANGE FROM 2 to 4
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 39).Value = Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1, 28).Value 'Copy xxx number
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1, 37).ClearContents 'Clears Koop Column
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 28).Value = "HZ" 'Update Typ Column
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 53).Value = 4 'Update tag
            c1 = c1 + 1 'So we skip the whole set (EACH CASE 1 CONTAINS 2 LINES, one after the other)
            
        ElseIf Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 10).Value = 3 And Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 11).Value = 4 Then
            'CHANGE FROM 3 to 4
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 39).Value = Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1, 28).Value 'Copy xxx number
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 28).Value = "HZ" 'Update Type Column
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1, 37).ClearContents 'Clears Koop Column
            Worksheets("20190328").Cells(c1 + 1, 53).Value = 4 'Update tag
            c1 = c1 + 1 'So we skip the whole set (EACH CASE 1 CONTAINS 2 LINES, one after the other)
        End If
    Next k1
End sub
```

I'm expecting the following type of comparisons to actually work:

```
If Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 3).Value = "FB" And Worksheets("20190328").Cells(row_counter + 1, 28).Value = "HZ Beistellung" Then
```

No errors appeared so far

Comment: Have you gone through in debug?  I think hovering over Cells would show the value at that time.  If not you could set a temporary variable i.e. vTemp=Worksheets("LogDetails").Cells(k1, 2).Value and then hover over vTemp to see the actual value.

Comment: Thanks! It worked just fine :)